# The field is not visible

Tags: java

So I wanted to make a 'Ball' class that extends a 'Thing' class. I call the super command for variables that are shared (ex. x,y,sizeX) in the constructor. But when I try to use them (specifically in the jump function) it gives me the error 'MeTryingToMakeAGame.Thing.x is not visible'

Please note that the name of my project is 'MeTryingToMakeAGame.'

```
class Ball extends Thing {

  Ball(int x, int y, int sizeX, int sizeY, int speed, int jumpheight) {
    super(x,y,sizeX,sizeY);

  }

  void jump() {
    x-=jumpHeight;
  }
}

class Thing {
  private int x;
  private int y;
  private int sizeX;
  private int sizeY;

  Thing (int x, int y, int sizeX, int sizeY) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.sizeX = sizeX;
    this.sizeY = sizeY;
  }
}
```

Comment: They are `private` so implement getter methods.

Answer (score 0):

Field `x` is private, so it is visible only in class `Thing`.
To make fields / methods visible for subclasses, use modifier `protected`.

Answer (score 0):

Because x is private, you cannot access it directly. In order to access it, you can create a getter method for the x field in the Thing class